# Subgroup ranks of the symmetric group

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

It's well known that every subgroup $G$ of $S_n$ has a generating set of size at most $n-1$ and that this generating set can be found algorithmically (by Jerrum's filter)

I have heard many times a stronger result, which is that for all $n>3$, every subgroup $G$ of $S_n$ has a generating set of size at most $n/2$. Note that this would be tight: for example, $n/2$ disjoint transpositions cannot be minimized further.

However, as far as I can tell, none of the places I have seen this theorem give a proof, nor do their references. Can anyone point me to a proper proof, or give one, for this seemingly important theorem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some googling, one finds a few references. Most point to

Cameron, Peter J.; Solomon, Ron; Turull, Alexandre, Chains of subgroups in symmetric groups. J. Algebra 127 (1989), no. 2, 340–352.

Which itself attributes this to Peter Neumann, private communication.

They also say: "As Peter is unlikely to publish his result, we shall sketch a recipe for a proof of Neumann’s theorem here.
" (And then proceed to give a sketch.)

Note that the proof seems to depend on the Classification of Finite Simple Groups (to deal with the case of primitive permutation groups).

Comment: Cameron has the paper available through [his ResearchGate page](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243018946_Chains_of_subgroups_in_symmetric_groups), for anyone looking for an easily accessed copy.